# Does RabbitMQ make delivery guarantees if a message is published (confirms-enabled) to a queue with a free consumer?

Tags: sockets, networking, concurrency, rabbitmq, latency

**Context:**

Say I do the following with RabbitMQ:

1. Connect a consumer to a queue `Q` in RabbitMQ.

   - This consumer can be in `noack` mode, or not; makes no difference.
   - If not in `noack` mode; assume that this consumer has set `basic.qos` and `channel.flow` such that it can receive messages; its buffer is not full and it is able to consume.
2. Connect a publisher to the same RabbitMQ cluster, and publish a *mandatory* message (with [publish confirmations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) enabled) to `Q`.
3. Receive a `basic.ack` in the publisher.

**Questions:**

- When that `basic.ack` is returned, is RabbitMQ guaranteed to have sent that message to the consumer's remote socket? I know it can't guarantee that the message has *arrived* in the consumer's local socket buffer, but I'm interested in whether the broker sent it or not.
- Does the presence/absence of `mandatory` publication affect these guarantees in any way?
- Does whether or not the queue is completely empty before the publication of the message affect these guarantees in any way?
- Does the version of RabbitMQ routing messages affect these guarantees in any way (i.e. are these guarantees only present in certain RMQ versions)?
- Does the durability of the message affect these guarantees in any way?
- Does whether or not the destination RMQ is [clustered](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) affect these guarantees in any way?
- Does the presence/absence of per-message expiration times affect these guarantees in any way?

**TL;DR: Are there any circumstances in which RMQ guarantees, *to the publisher* that a published message has been sent from the broker to a consumer?**

**What I've Tried:**

I've tried testing this with connecting consumers and publishing messages to variously-configured queues. The messages have usually been received by the time that the `basic.ack` has been received. However, I can't infer any guarantees from this, since latency and confusion is introduced in many places:

- The transit time of the `basic.ack` back to the publisher.
- The transit time of the message body to the consumer.
- Synchronizing the tracking clocks between the publisher and consumer (if they are on separate hosts/in separate processes) make this hard to prove.

As a result, I'm seeking knowledge of guarantees provided by the broker itself due to its internal code flow, since verifying these things externally (absent a fuzzer or something like [jepsen](http://jepsen.io/)).

Comment: We approach this (being able to verify particular consumers received and processed published messages) by using unique CorrelationIds on messages, and logging at publishers/subscribers of messages sent/received, in a separate logging database designed specifically for this.  _If_ we laterneed to verify a particular message workflow succeeded, we use a lens on that logging to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any circumstances in which RMQ guarantees, to the publisher that a published message has been sent from the broker to a consumer?

no.

An `ack` for a publisher is a statement that the message has been received by the RabbitMQ exchange, and will be routed.

You could, for example, route the message into oblivion by using a routing key that is not connected to a queue. In that case, the publisher still receives the `ack`, because the message was published. It just didn't go anywhere.

Comment: That is actually not completely true. If you get the ack it means the message has been routed (if it has been routable). But you are right that if  it cannot be routed to any queue it will not go anywhere.